# Cronjob doesn't run Python script even though it has execute permissions and a hashbang to full path of python. Works normally outside of the cronjob

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron, python-3.5

My crons are working normally, I tested it with simple file outputs and bash scripts, but nothing I have tried works when it comes to executing my python script.

So this is what I did.

as per usual I added a shebang to my script

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.5
```

&

```
chmod +x myPythonScript.py
```

I added it to crontab -e and tested on various ways.

examples:

```
* * * * * /path/to/myPythonScript.py
```

and just to be sure I even did the following

```
* * * * * python /path/to/myPythonScript.py

* * * * * python3.5 /path/to/myPythonScript.py

* * * * * /usb/bin/python /path/to/myPythonScript.py

* * * * * /usb/bin/python3.5 /path/to/myPythonScript.py
```

and even did */1 * * * * and other time tests.

Nothing worked, and if I write all of these outside the cron, everything works perfectly fine every time. I even changed the SHELL in the crontab -e knowing that it will not make any difference, but just to be sure, pasted the script in /etc/cron.hourly, nope, tried with /usr/bin/env python instead of the usual shebang, tried every other dumb thing, but it did not work out.

Cronjobs worked perfectly when running a bash script, I even ran a bash script to check if my python script is up and running and to notify me about that in a text log, and if its not, to restart it and also notify me about that, my text log was full of restarts and that was because it never ran the python script, so the cron was working obviously, because it ran the bash script.

Comment: Have you tested to confirm that your Python script is not simply launching but failing (for instance due to the environment being different from the one you have in you interactive shell)?   You could try adding MAILTO=USERNAME at the top of your cron file to see if you receive mail that would help you understand, or add debugging statements to your Python script that would let you see if it actually starts and where it fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running cron, you should always write your standard out/err to a file to see whats happening. Don't trust mail because your mail server may/maynot be setup.

So, give this a try

```
* * * * * python /path/to/myPythonScript.py 1>/tmp/myPythonScript.out 2>/tmp/myPythonScript.err
```

After 1 minute check to see if the file /tmp/myPythonScript.{out,err} exist. This will give you a clear direction of what is happening.

Again, ALWAYS write your standard out/err

Comment: Thank you! This helped me diagnose the problem. In my case, my python script is outputting some results in a text file, and the text file was just set up as "log.txt" in the python code, so I changed it to the exact path, like this: with open(r'exact/path/to/log.txt', 'r') as f, instead of what I used before: with open('log.txt', 'r') as f.

Comment: glad it worked out. the trick is to always put stdout and stderr so its easier to see whats going on